# Deploying new PHP code and run composer on all AWS Beanstalk instances via Jenkins?

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm new to Jenkins so I have a question about deployment. My site is running on Amazon Beanstalk via Docker (auto-scaling). Currently there are 3 running instances and my PHP app is in `/var/www`.

What I'd like to do is whenever I make a `git push` (assuming test passes), I want to automatically update each running EC2 instances (started by Beanstalk) with the new PHP code and then run `composer install` on it.

Right now the command I see people using on Jenkins to update the servers is something like `rsync` and then ssh into the server to run `composer update`.

Since I'm not creating the instances (Beanstalk is) I don't know the IP addresses of my instances so I can't put that in my Jenkins job (like the tutorials).

So my question is: How can my Jenkinks trigger a code update and `composer install` on my already running instances (and any newly created instances) started by Amazon Beanstalk?

**What is the correct way of doing this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use CodePipeline to do this exact thing with my rails App.

CodePipeline is a free service that controls your deployments and I deploy and execute builds and test using just `git push`.

Create a pipeline that uses your git repo as the source. Then for build stage under build provider select "Add Jenkins", enter the server URL and project name. Next for Beta select AWS ElasticBeanstalk as the deployment provider, select your application and environment that you want ElasticBeanstalk to deploy to and you're set.

What's happening is you're telling CodePipeline to watch a specific branch of your git repo for changes. When it notices changes you want it to execute the pipeline. When CP sees a change it's going to go to github, grab the code, build the package and usher the package through the pipeline. For the build stage it will pass the package to Jenkins and let Jenkins do it's thing. When Jenkins sends the success message back to CodePipeline, CodePipeline will execute the next step in the pipeline. In this case you're telling CodePipeline that you want it to invoke ElasticBeanstalk to deploy your application. So it passes the package to ElasticBeanstalk and says "do your thing". Which EB does.

So we now have Jenkins triggering your code updates and we now just need to run `composer install` on all the instances, post deployment. You can do this by creating a .config file in the .ebextensions directory. You'll create a container command like this:

```
#.ebextensions/composer.config

container_commands:
  01_first_line:
    command: cd /var/www
  02_second_line
    command: composer install
```

The container command will execute after the server has been stood up, and after the application version has been extracted, but before it is deployed. As a Rubyist I'm not sure if `composer install` needs to be executed pre-deployment, post deployment or if it doesn't matter. You can find the AWS docs on customizing the Linux software on your server here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-container-commands one of which will allow you to run `composer install` at the appropriate time.

Comment: Thank you for making it so easy to understand. Three questions regarding deployment from Code pipeline to EB. How does that happen? Q1) I'm using a custom Docker image (zip file with PHP code, a Dockerfile file and .ebextensions dir) to deploy my site on EB. Q2) Does it terminate my running instances and start new instances when `git push` happens? Q3) Is there a downtime?

Comment: My pleasure... Please don't forget to select it as the answer :). In response to your questions 1) is a statement, no question there, 2) no, EB deploys to the same running instances, 3) no downtime.